# Why does my image in Firebase Storage render only after reload 404 error

Tags: reactjs, authentication, async-await, firebase-storage, use-effect

I am able to upload the image successfully to Firebase Storage, but when I try to render it back to my dashboard I get a 404 error, file not found.  I figure it has to do with the database not uploading the image and then sending it back to my react app.  When I reload the page, the image renders.  I have an async/await function for setting the userImage. What is the best way to manage this?  New to React btw.

```
import { useState, createContext, useEffect } from "react";
import app from "../firebase";

const UserContext = createContext();

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [userImg, setUserImage] = useState(null);

  console.log("userImg from context", userImg);

  const img = async () => {
    const imgPath = await app.firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(`users/${user.uid}/profile.jpg`)
      .getDownloadURL();
    setUserImage(imgPath);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) img();
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser);
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[user, setUser, userImg, setUserImage]}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { UserContext, UserProvider };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the `component` gets rendered before even the `img` is retrieved from the `server`.

So what you can do is have a `loading state` in your `component` and until the `img` isn't received back from the `server` set the `loading state` to `true`.

```
import { useState, createContext, useEffect } from "react";
import app from "../firebase";

const UserContext = createContext();

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false) // <--------Loading state-------- 
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [userImg, setUserImage] = useState(null);

  console.log("userImg from context", userImg);

  const img = async () => {
    setLoading(true) // Setloading to true
    const imgPath = await app.firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(`users/${user.uid}/profile.jpg`)
      .getDownloadURL();
    setUserImage(imgPath);
    setLoading(false) // <--------setting loading to false after receiving the image-------
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) img();
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser);
  }, [user]);

  if(loading) {
    return (<div>Loading...</div>)  // <-----return loading if loading is true----
  }

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[user, setUser, userImg, setUserImage]}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { UserContext, UserProvider };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help,  unfortunately I am still getting the same error.  As soon as I submit my form, I am getting a 404 error.  I get redirected to my dashboard and firebase is running a git request for that file, which is not found.  I am at a loss right now

Comment: I don't see any form in the code you shared in your question. Are you sure we have a [minimal, complete repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?